# Evitar que se muestre NaN en un input con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una función *onchange* que valida una diferencia de fechas:

```js
        $('#fechaFinal').on('change',function(){
       $('#ndias').val('');
       var fechaInicio = new Date($('#fechaInicio').val());
        var fechaFinal = new Date($('#fechaFinal').val());
        var fechaResta = fechaFinal - fechaInicio;
        $('#ndias').val(((((fechaResta / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24).toFixed(0));

 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="">Fecha Inicio</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" value="" placeholder="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" required="true">
 </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="">Fecha Final</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaFinal" value="" placeholder="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" required="true">
 </div>
    //este es otro form-group
    <div class="col-md-6">
  <label for="">Dias Vacacionales</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ndias" value='' placeholder="Dias" name="dias" required="true" readonly="true">
 </div>
```

El detalle es que a pesar de ser una función `onchange` el input `ndias` me aparece como **NaN** al cargar la pagina hasta que se ejecuta la función,
no hay error en el proceso pero se ve muy feo ese **NaN**

Comment: añade también el código html

Comment: Al cargar la pagina que valores tiene $('#fechaInicio') y final? ya que le has puesto un `change` a `document` y no a un elemento, como por ejemplo a cualquiera de #fechaInicio o #fechaFinal, entonces si uno de ellos o los dos no tienen valor numerico, si o si, #ndias saldrá NaN

Comment: Es cierto @jolsalazar gracias, no tienen value, intente dandoles un value=1 para probar y es cierto, ahora cambie el $(document).ready por $('#fechaFinal').on('change',function(){ dejando value='' en fecha inicio y fechafinal pero sigue NaN

Comment: podrías añadir el codigo HTML donde estan estos inputs

Comment: listo @jolsalazar ya los agregue.

Comment: @matteo, por favor actualiza tu pregunta agregando el campo `#ndias` y ejemplos de valores que estás usando.

Comment: listo @MauricioAriasOlave, esta actualizado.

Comment: @matteom, ¿el campo #ndias tiene datos cuando haces algún cambio en el campo `fechaFinal`?

Comment: si @MauricioAriasOlave al cambiar el campo fechaFinal  se ejecuta la funcion y en campo ndias ahora vale la dif de fechaFinal y fechaInicio.

Comment: las fechas las ingresas '10/10/2010' o '10-10-2010'?

Comment: @matteo pudiste realizar la prueba? de la respuesta que dí?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prueba con isNan() con un ternario para que solo te muestre en caso de que no sea NaN

```
$('#fechaFinal').on('change',function(){
    $('#ndias').val('');
    var fechaInicio = new Date($('#fechaInicio').val());
    var fechaFinal = new Date($('#fechaFinal').val());
    var fechaResta = fechaFinal - fechaInicio;
    var dias = ((((fechaResta / 1000) / 60) / 60) / 24;
    $('#ndias').val(!isNaN(dias) ? dias : '').toFixed(0));
});
```

Por otro lado prueba borrando el caché ya que te puede estar tomando aún el $(document).ready() y no el documento js actualizado, me suele pasar.

Comment: Cool brod, gracias funciona de maravilla!

Answer (score 2):

Prueba esto:

```js
$('#fechaFinal').on('change',function(){
    $('#ndias').val('');
    var fechaInicio = $('#fechaInicio').val();
    var fechaFinal = $('#fechaFinal').val();
  
    date1 = new Date(fechaInicio.split('/')[2],fechaInicio.split('/')[1]-1,fechaInicio.split('/')[0]);
    date2 = new Date(fechaFinal.split('/')[2],fechaFinal.split('/')[1]-1,fechaFinal.split('/')[0]);
    var timeDiff = Math.abs(date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
    var diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

  $('#ndias').val(diffDays)

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="">Fecha Inicio</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaInicio" value="" placeholder="fechaInicio" name="fechaInicio" required="true">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="">Fecha Final</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="fechaFinal" value="" placeholder="fechaFinal" name="fechaFinal" required="true">
</div>
//este es otro form-group
<div class="col-md-6">
    <label for="">Dias Vacacionales</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ndias" value='' placeholder="Dias" name="dias" required="true" readonly="true">
</div>
```

Me cuentas,

Comment: que tal @jolsalazar, si probe el codigo lamentablemente el problema persiste.

Answer (score 2):

Para que no veas el valor **NaN** en el campo `#ndias` deberías tener un valor por defecto en ese campo *#ndias*. Establece el valor 0. Así no tendrías ese problema.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ndias" value='0' placeholder="Dias" name="dias" required="true" readonly="true">
```

Si ese campo debe estar vacío *(al cargar tu página)*, debes validar que *cuando cargue la página* si `#ndias` es `NaN` o está vacío, debes ponerle un valor por defecto al campo.

Comment: Gracias por responder, ya lo he probado y sigue sin desaparecer el NaN aun poniendo un value por defecto en ndias, hasta ahora lo unico que funciona es poner un valor en fechaFinal y FechaInicial, pero los campos deben estar vacios ya que son tipo date.

Comment: @matteo, `pero los campos deben estar vacíos ya que son tipo date` prueba colocando fechas por defecto en esos campos. Me genera inquietud que _incluso con mi sugerencia_ sigas viendo el NaN. Por favor actualiza tu pregunta agregando el código que usas cuando carga la página.